# Two arrays and number-- best algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

This is a question I got in a job interview:

You are given two sorted arrays (sizes n and m), and a number x. What would be the best algorithm to find the indexes of two numbers (one from each array), that their sum equals the given number.

I couldn't find a better answer than the naive solution which is:

1. Start from the smaller array, from the cell that contains the largest number which is smaller than x.
2. For each cell in small array. do binary search on the big one, looking for the number so the sum will equal x.
3. Continue until the first cell of the smaller array, returning the appropriate indexes.
4. Return FALSE if no such numbers exist.

Can anyone think of a better solution in terms of runtime?

Comment: you can adapt this problem http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/

Comment: i dont see how that is related

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed? Is there a known range for each array (in case the numbers are integers)?

Comment: its a pseudocode question, sorted means sorted-- increasing order.
further details are irrelevant because its a theoretical question. memory managment is not the focus here, but rather running time.

Comment: you can hash one array , then pass over other array . This uses memory .

Comment: for the sake of argument --- array contains POSITIVE INTEGERS ONLY. i canonly think of one way to sort numbers- by size

Comment: Are there duplicated elements???

Comment: Try starting from the low end of one array and the high end of the other array, and move the indices in the opposite directions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use two indices `i1,i2` - set `i1=0, i2=n-1`

```
while i1 < m && i2>=0:
    if arr1[i1] + arr2[i2] == SUM:
         return i1,i2
    else if arr1[i1] + arr2[i2] > SUM:
         i2--
    else
         i1++
return no pair found
```

The idea is to use the fact that the array is sorted, so start from the two edges of the arrays, and at each iteration, make changes so you will get closer to the desired element

Complexity is `O(n+m)` under worst case analysis, which is better than binary search approach if `min{m,n} >= log(max{m,n})`

**Proof of correctness (guidelines):**

Assume the answer is `true` with indices `k1,k2`.

Then, for each `i2>k2`- `arr1[k1] + arr2[i2] > SUM` - and you will NOT change `i1` after  reaching it before getting to `i2==k2`. Similarly you can show that when you get to `i2==k2`, you will NOT change `i2` before you get `i1==k1`.

Since we linearly scan the arrays - one of `i1` or `i2` will get to `k1` or `k2` at some point, and then - you will continue iterating until you set the other iterator to the correct location, and find the answer.

**QED**

**Notes:**

 If you want to output ALL elements that matches the desired sum, when `arr1[i1]+arr2[i2] ==SUM`, change the element with the LOWER absolute difference to the next element in the iteration order. It will make sure you output all desired pairs.

Note that this solution might fail for duplicate elements. As is, the solution works if there is no pair (x,y) such that x AND y both have dupes.

To handle this case, you will need to 'go back up' once you have exhausted all possible pairs in one direction, and the pseudo code should be updated to:

```
dupeJump = -1
while i1 < m && i2>=0:
    if arr1[i1] + arr2[i2] == SUM:
         yield i1,i2
         if arr1[i1+1] == arr1[i1] AND arr2[i2-1] == arr2[i2]:
             //remembering where we were in case of double dupes
             if (dupeJump == -1):
                 dupeJump = i2
             i2--
         else:
             if abs(arr1[i1+1] - arr1[i1]) < abs(arr2[i2-1] - arr2[i2]):
                 i1++
             else:
                 i2--
            //going back up, because there are more pairs to print due to dupes
             if (dupeJump != -1):
                 i2 = dupeJump 
                 dupeJump = -1
    else if arr1[i1] + arr2[i2] > SUM:
         i2--
    else
         i1++
```

Note however that the time complexity might increase to `O(n+m+size(output))`, because there could `O(n*m)` such pairs and you need to output all of them (note that every correct solution will have this restriction).

Comment: How do you update i1, i2 when their sum is expected? And take care of duplicated elements!

Comment: i dont see any differnce between that and the solution i offered. am i wrong? or are you approving mine?

Comment: @davyx8 There is no binary search here. binary search will make the solution `O(min{mlogn,nlogm})`. This solution is `O(n+m)` - which is better in terms of asymptotic complexity (but is worse if one of the arrays is very small comparing to the other one).

Comment: @herohuyongtao If we are supposed to find ALL such pairs, I simply update the one that has the smaller absolute difference to the next element. It also take care of duplicates automatically.

Comment: +1, for further note of `O(n+m+size(output))` to find all pairs.